# Change remote upstream w/o affecting more recent commits

Tags: git, drupal

We have a drupal 9 codebase that we use as a template, and spin up sites for localization and minor css and theme changes. This site wasn't using composer, the modules were committed to the repo. We are trying to fix this.

We created a composer-based repo, and want to connect all the older sites to this new remote and track changes from their.

Each site also has a number of small CSS and theme changes that we want to keep. We are trying to figure out the best way to do this with git.

After `git branch branch_name --set-upstream-to new_remote/branch_name`

I was thinking that I create a new branch, then `git pull --theirs new-repo` then cherry pick and apply the newer commits from the newer repo? Some repos have like 50 commits, so that would be prone to error. I have a feeling there is a better way.